# Firebase Realtime Database gives incorrect server time offset value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following code in my PWA to calculate client's clock skew with respect to the Firebase Realtime Database's servers based on the docs:-

```
var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
});
```

However, the issue is that on some devices I get strange values like -13181 for offset, making it off by almost 13 seconds! Hence the countdown timer of 20 seconds on that device starts from 7 seconds because in reality the offset is much lower. Yesterday, one machine got the above value consistently (-13181) even though it was working fine earlier. Is there any reason why devices on the same network will report such huge differences in the time offset value? How can I fix this issue? The countdown timer being synced across different devices is very critical to my app.

Comment: I had a regression bug in my code because of which offset was being ignored. My app is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the context from our conversation yesterday, you said:

> We made a quiz application where even thousands of people can play in
>   real time and so everyone has to see the same value on the countdown
>   timer. Our logic is working pretty well except for the fact that
>   rarely I get strange offset values.

As much as possible, you don't want to depend on the client's clock. There is already some variance inevitable based on people's network quality and distance from the server, so as you've seen, adding an unreliable local clock can exacerbate this. Timing for online games is no small task and I won't claim to have the best solution, but here's a suggestion to try:

Have a source of truth, likely a server, which keeps track of the time remaining in the game and updates it in the database. You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access the database from you server, which may be how you're already inputting the timestamp right now anyway.

Writing to the database from the Admin SDK will look something like this:

```
admin.database().ref(".info/timeRemaining").set({
  time_remaining: time_remaining
});
```

Where `time_remaining` will be the time that you update each second.

Then on the client, instead of tracking the offset, you just have the time remaining.

```
var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/timeRemaining");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  // do what you will
});
```

Then you can have rules on the client that end the game at 0. Of course developers could find ways around this, so if possible, it would be better to include a sever check. If clients are also writing to the database but you don't want them to be able to once the time limit has passed, one option is to use rules. Now your rules will look different depending on your data structure. I'm just speculating on applying writes to any child of `".info"`, which probably isn't exactly what you need.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".info": {
      "$info": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        // writes can only happen before the timer reaches 0
        ".write": "data.parent().child('time_remaining').val() > 0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This rule only allows users to write to that location while the value of `time_remaining` is greater than 0. If they try to write after this, an error will be returned and you can handle displaying this on the client.

Comment: Thanks Jen! One issue seems to be that there will be a lot of reads involved every second and the clock might not move smoothly. I was trying out the approach discussed at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93477/how-to-keep-server-client-clocks-in-sync-for-precision-networked-games-like-quak

In my case, I set the start time as firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP and then take the difference between (local time + offset) and start time to get the number of seconds. Should I figure out another way of calculating offset instead of using .info/serverTimeOffset?

Comment: I had a regression bug in my code because of which offset was being ignored. My app is working properly. I am glad I have another solution as well for the countdown timer.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal I have same issue. can you post you full code to see how it works with firebase function and firebase client the issue with the time?

Comment: Thank you! This is the best solution I have ever seen regarding this topic.